# error in building link list in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have written condition in while loop but error

> curr undeclared(first use in this function)

occurs though I have used the variable curr in insert function.

```
insert(struct node **start)
         { struct node *temp;
           temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node);
           temp-> data=75;
           temp->next= NULL;
           if(*start==NULL)
           {*start= temp;} 
           else
           {struct node *curr=*start;}
           while(curr->next!=NULL)
           {curr= curr->next;
           curr-> next= temp;
                                  }

                       }
```

Comment: Your formatting is atrocious. Please, for the love of all that is good, read some good C code and format your code correctly and consistently. Then, we will be able to maybe explain to you how *scope* works. But only once your blocks are visible as *blocks*.

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should never have spaces on either side.  The compiler doesn't mind, but for the sanity of those reading your code.  (I also wholly agree with the comment that the formatting shown is abysmal.  Avoid anything resembling [Pico style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Pico_style) — this is C, not Pico — and use Allman or a 1TBS  variant instead.)

Comment: Come on, look at how the majority of the code snippets around here is formatted ...

Comment: You have to declare it outside your `else` clause.

Answer (score 5):

When you declare a variable in C it is scoped to the nearest surrounding block.

For example:

```
if (something) {
    /* foo is declared here and so it is limited to between these
     * {} brackets */
    int foo = 3;
    printf("%i\n", foo);
}
/* ERROR! foo is not declared here because we are outside the {} */
printf("%i\n", foo);
```

I think the problem is that you've put the closing `}` bracket too soon whereas you actually wanted the while-loop to be inside the block for the else-statement.

It would help if you tidied up the indentation of the code to make the structure more clear. I think there are various other missing brackets such as the one to close the call to `malloc` which prevent the code from being compiled.

**edit:** I think the correct version of the function would look like this (note, I haven't tested this apart from compiling it):

```
void
insert (struct node **start)
{
        struct node *temp;
        temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
        temp->data = 75;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (*start == NULL) {
                *start = temp;
        }
        else {
                struct node *curr = *start;
                while (curr->next != NULL) {
                        curr = curr->next;
                }
                curr->next = temp;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this else statement

```
else
           {struct node *curr=*start;}
```

variable `curr` has scope of the compound statement that is the sub-statement of the else.

```
{struct node *curr=*start;}
```

Thus it is not visible and alive in the following while statement

```
      while(curr->next!=NULL)
       {curr= curr->next;
       curr-> next= temp;
                              }
```

I think you meant that the while statement will be included in the compound statement of the else statement.

In any case your insert function is too complicated. It can be written simpler as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int insert( struct node **start, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        while ( *start ) start = &( *start )->next;
        *start = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( struct node *start )
{
    for ( ; start; start = start->next ) printf( "%d ", start->data );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    struct node *start = NULL;
    const int N = 10;

    int i = 1;
    while ( i <= N && insert( &start, i ) ) ++i;

    display( start );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Of course you need to write other methods as for example the method that deletes all allocated memory for the list yourself.